# How to keep the Yocto workspace minimal when building for multiple boards?

Tags: yocto

I would like to know what the best practice is to keep the Yocto workspace as small as possible. Currently, I am creating a separate build folder for every board. I wonder if there is a better way to reuse as many packages as possible. Can you just build in the same folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you base on the same core yocto system you can use "distro" feature.

What I was attempting to convey to you is that you should move your "distro"
parameters into the "machine" config. Then just build for multiple machines.
If you want to have multiple image types, just create multiple image recipes,
and build them in the same directory and save disk space.

You can use the whole build tree for multiple machines. Changing DISTRO has
lots of extra effects on packages, in the past it wasn't possible at all
without wiping tmp, and it still is not a nice thing to do, as you have
discovered for yourself now.

You'd invoke your build like this:

```
for machine in apple-pie orange-pie banana-pie
do
   MACHINE=$machine bitbake red-image blue-image green-image
done
```

You can build multiple images for the same machine in parallel, and you can
build multiple machine in the same environment (not in parallel yet,
unfortunately, but you probably don't have that many machines that this might
really help).

Comment: We already have two machine configs, but they are built on different repos. because the other requires a different kernel. I did not come up with the structuring and want to find a way to simplify the workflow as much as possbile. I am fairly new to Yocto though and don't have the required overview yet.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed building everything in one folder is the preferred way for yocto (although it's not mentioned explicitly in the [getting started doc](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html#qs-building-images)). Yocto will take care of reusing as much as possible it can and this will avoid having duplicate files and build procedures.